# Nested large tables in itext7

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I've seen that the best way of handling large tables in itext 7 is explained in http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/clone-large-tables

I have a table inside another one. What if the large table is the inner one?

```
Table outTable = new Table(new float[]{1f},true);

Cell cellHeader1 = new Cell();
cellHeader1.add(new Paragraph("Header 1").addStyle(style));
outTable.addHeaderCell(cellHeader1);

document.add(outTable);

for (int i=0; i<smallArray.size();i++) {
    Table innerTable = new Table(new float[]{0.5f,0.5f},true);
    Cell cellHeader2 = new Cell(1,2);
    cellHeader2.add(new Paragraph("Header 2").addStyle(style));
    innerTable.addHeaderCell(cellHeader2);

    Cell cellInnerTable = new Cell();
    cellInnerTable.add(innerTable);
    outTable.addCell(cellInnerTable);

    for(int j=0;j<bigArray.size();j++){
        //add cells to innerTable;
        if (j%20==0){
            innerTable.flush();  (1)
            outTable.flush(); (2)
        }
    }

    innerTable.complete(); (1)
}
outTable.complete();
```

(2) This flush doesn't solve the memory problem.

(1) These lines return a NullPointerException in the Table object, line 539 because document is null. The outTable's parent is the document so the 'flush' method flushes the data into the document, but the innerTable's parent is the outTable, not the document. Is there a way of having the innerTable flushed into the outTable and the outTable into the document?

If I set the document to the innerTable so I don't get the NullPointerException:
innerTable.setDocument(document);

it doesn't behave as it should, because now the innerTable is being flushed into the document, not into the outTable and it does weird things.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, large tables are only supported if you add them directly to the `Document`. Inner large tables are not supported and there are no plans to add support for inner large tables in the nearest future.

Comment: That's a pity. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for(int j=0;j<bigArray.size();j++){
    //add cells to innerTable;
    if (j%20==0){
        Cell cellContent = new Cell(1,2).add(innerTable);
        outTable.addCell(cellContent);
        innerTable.flushContent();  // API says is internal but is public and works OK
        outTable.flush();
    }
}
```